# What is the difference between "Some would argue that..." vs "Some may argue that..."?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

What is the difference between these two expressions:
"Some would argue that..." vs "Some may argue that..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [May vs can, could or would](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70784/may-vs-can-could-or-would)

Comment: ***Arguably***, using ***may*** is slightly more "tentative" than ***would*** for your context (some ***may*** argue, but then again they may ***not***). But in practice it really doesn't make any difference which "hedge" you use - either you make the bald assertion ***Some argue that blah blah***, or you "temper" it with ***will / would / may / might / can / could / ...*** And if you want to be even *more* tentative, maybe introduce the claim with ***Feasibly**, some might argue blah blah*.